# Keyboard style different from region language

Tags: keyboard-layout, system-language

I am booting ubuntu LTS in English from a USB-Stick, but the computer I am on has a German keyboard, so it is a real typing adventure. Is it possible to change the keyboard to German style and keep the system language in English? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open System Settings, and click keyboard:

[image]

Click input sources:

[image]

Click +:

[image]

Find German (I had to search you probably will just have to scroll), select it and click Add.

[image]

Chose that as your default.

Comment: Works great. What a relief! Many Thanx -John

Comment: Pleasure :) Sorry if mine looks different to yours and it was hard to follow (I use a different ubuntu)

Comment: No Problem. Small differences, but the screenshots helped a lot, so I made it. Thanx again! I am really very happy that this is working now :-)))))))